# Laravel's morphOne/morphTo returns null

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to display multiple images for one product.
I have tried creating regular hasMany/belongsTo relations, but my query duplicates products for each image that belongs to it. Hence I decided to use morphOne polymorphic relation. I've read a bunch of questions/answers here, and on google overall and haven't been able to find my answer, or maybe i just did not understand how everything works.

Following Laravels documentation, i have the following:

```php
Product model

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Image::class, 'imageable');
    }

Image model

    protected $fillable = [
        'image', 'imageable_id', 'imageable_type'
    ];

    public function imageable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

Image migration

        Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->integer('imageable_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('imageable_type');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Database image

https://ibb.co/bd8VsCK

Image Factory

    $noteable = App\Image::class;

    return [
        'image' =>$faker>image(storage_path('app/public/products'),400,300,'',false), 
        'imageable_type' => $noteable,
        'imageable_id' => $faker->numberBetween(1,20),
    ];
```

Maybe I am missing something, or maybe this approach is not suitable for what I want. I am fairly new to Laravel so any help would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a very complicated solution that you are trying to achieve. What I've done previously on my projects would be to have two tables hence two php models, one would be Product.php and ProductItem.php (Images);

```
class Product extends Model 
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function images() {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductImage::class);
    }

}

class ProductItem extends Model 
{
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

on your controller methods, the way you would query your products would be

```
public function index() 
{
    $products = Product::with('images')->get();
}
```

your database schemas would be

```
products table 
    - name
    - id
    - ....

product_items table
    - id
    - product_id
    - path or image or name
```

Comment: I had this system set up before, but your query made everything work. Thank you !